# Read sequence of images in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have created a program reading images in the sequence. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cv::namedWindow("Example3", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(string("F:/8TH SEMESTER/trial/%05d.ppm"));
//"F:/8TH SEMESTER/Traffic Sign Dectection/GTSDB/FullIJCNN2013/FullIJCNN2013/01/%05d.ppm"
cv::Mat frame;
for (;;) {
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) break;             // Ran out of film
    cv::imshow("Example3", frame);
    if (cv::waitKey(2000) >= 0) break;
}

return 0;

}
```

it works perfectly with those images which have traffic sign and cars etc. But when I run this code with sample data, for example only with a 30-speed sign then it runs first time and stops? Why does this happen?

With this image, it works perfectly:
[image]

When I run it using the following image, it gives error.

[image]

Comment: JPEG images only have one frame, whereas GIF/PPM/TIFF files can have multiple frames in a single file. Is that the difference?

Comment: If you have **ImageMagick** installed, you can run `identify YourImage.gif` and you will see how many frames there are because you'll get one line of output per frame.

Comment: Check your path, file name, file extension etc. Also, make sure the images are all the same size.

Comment: I give correct path and image extension is 00000.ppm. The size of image is different like 2KB,10kB etc. How i solve this. Any body can code

Comment: I meant all the images must be the same size *in pixels and depth* not the file size.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you share the original `PPM` image please?

Comment: yes i have same size in pixels and depth because i am working on german data set

Comment: i have already upload two images..the first scene image which i upload is working correct and even read images in sequence, but the problem come when i give sample image mean just sign of 30 then it first image run and then give error. @MarkSetchell

Comment: Error come during run time:                                                                                                           
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvSetData, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 928
Press any key to continue . . .@AdiShavit

Comment: The code you provide only loads one image, not two. Your image is named with `%d` in its name which is asking for trouble. Your code loads a `PPM` image but you have provided a JPEG and a PNG. It's difficult to help you.

Comment: https://salman2004.imgur.com/all/        first 12 images of 30 signs when i run these kind of images it give errors but rest of 10 images it does not give error . i have 78 images of 30 sign which is save another folder. when i give this path it give error..i have 911 images of scene data which store in other folder when i give its path it does not give  errors....i am using german data set

Comment: i think now you understand my question @MarkSetchell

Comment: No, I still don't understand. Your code loads a `PPM` image (not `PNG`) and treats it as a video by reading multiple frames with `cap >> frame`. You have provided 12 PNG files, not `PPM` files. You cannot treat a `PNG` file as a video - it is one single frame, not a video. Please provide the actual code and the actual images that do not work.

Comment: its ppm file but when i upload it on stack overflow or imgur etc it automatically covert it into png or jpeg. if you have any idea how to upload ppm images on stack overflow ..tell i will upload it.@MarkSetchell

Comment: OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvSetData, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\cor‌​e\src\array.cpp, line 928 Press any key to continue                      give me this error @MarkSetchell